# Rotating a matrix CCW

Tags: java, matrix

I wrote a method that rotates a 2D matrix clockwise.

```
static double[][] rotateCW(double[][] mat) {
    final int M = mat.length;
    final int N = mat[0].length;
    double[][] ret = new double[N][M];
    for (int r = 0; r < M; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
            ret[c][M-1-r] = mat[r][c];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It works out well.. But I also want to create a method that rotates the matrix CCW, and I am unsure as to what values I need to change to do so. Currently, my "hack" is to use this method three times to rotate CCW.

Comment: how exactly does that rotate the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I think this way should work :

```
static double[][] rotateCCW(double[][] mat) {
    final int M = mat.length;
    final int N = mat[0].length;
    double[][] ret = new double[N][M];
    for (int r = 0; r < M; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
            ret[N-c-1][r] = mat[r][c];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```